# Intuitive understanding and practice of Group Lasso

Tags: regression, lasso, ridge-regression

I have been searching for a straight answer to clarify myself about the use of dummy variables in Lasso regression. I understand why we need to group them but I could not find any clear information on how we actually group them. My understanding is that (let's assume my categorical variable is crash type that has 4 sub levels

| Crash Type 1 | Crash Type 2 | Crash Type 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |

I group 2-3, and create a single variable then pick only this (Crash Type2-3, do not include crash type since it is my reference point) in my Lasso

| Crash Type 1 | Crash Type 2-3 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |

Do I understand this correctly? Is it what we mean by group lasso

Thanks

Comment: See https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity/ for a definition of the group lasso  (4.3 The Group Lasso page 58)

Answer (score 1):

For Group LASSO you just use any coding scheme that gives a sub-matrix of full rank for each group; e.g. reference-level coding for a categorical predictor, in this case giving columns of indicator variables for 'Crash Type 2' & 'Crash Type 3'. The L1-norm penalty is applied to the groupwise L2-norms of the coefficients, ensuring that either all coefficients in a group are shrunk to zero or none of them. And usually you orthonormalize each sub-matrix, ensuring that equivalent coding schemes result in equivalent models (e.g. it would make no odds if you picked 'Crash Type 3' as the reference level). See [Why use group lasso instead of lasso?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/214325/17230).

Even if you're using the ordinary LASSO, you still don't need to merge levels of categorical variables if you don't mind that some coefficients might be shrunk to zero & others not. (Some people overparametrize by using 'one-hot' encoding—including an indicator variable for *every* level— to avoid the model's depending on an arbitrary choice of reference level, though that doesn't apply to other situations where a predictor is represented by multiple columns in the design matrix.) An arbitrary merging of levels doesn't make much sense, & destroys potentially predictive information. If sparsity of level coefficients within a categorical variable is in fact among your goals, there are principled ways of merging levels—you might be interested in some version of the Fused Lasso (see [Penalized methods for categorical data: combining levels in a factor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/60100/17230)).